# Manage large area of private OSM server

Tags: openstreetmap, josm

I did setup sucessfully a OSM Website following tutorial at https://github.com/openstreetmap/openstreetmap-website

I have now an OSM server empty of vectors.
Now I want to import some data of shp format distributed along the whole country of Brazil.
I tried using JOSM, but when I try to retrieve the data from my server it says that the area is too big (even a medium city it says that its too big.

[image]

Is there a way of importing and deleting data of large areas using JOSM?

Comment: You can load multiple small areas in JOSM until having loaded the full country. However you will need a very fast system with a lot of RAM. JOSM is not made for editing such huge areas.

Comment: The reason for this error message is a simple heuristic in JOSM to anticipate a 50'000 node limit in the API. If you don't like that, patch your JOSM, or use something like continuous download.

Comment: @mmd that message appears even if I select a box with no data... how could I patch my JOSM or make a continuous download?

Comment: @mmd If you mean the plugin continuous download, I tried it and it doens't download if I zoom out for an area like a medium city, it still doesn't look like a doable way to manage a whole country data.

Comment: Heuristic means, that JOSMs makes some assumptions that there's lots of data in a larger bounding box, which is the case on the OSM database. It has no idea, that your own database is rather empty. Also, the API would reject too large bounding boxes (which you can avoid by using Overpass API). JOSM has a developer mailing list, maybe try asking there on how to get rid of this check.